# C - How to pass a char array to a function for sorting?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to compare strings in a mergesort algorithm after reading characters from a file as integers, and converting them to strings in an array.  I am able to get the strings to print out, but when the `char[]` array is passed to the mergesort algorithm, the program crashes at the `strcmp()` step which is in the `merge()` step of the merge sort.

I tested to see that my temp `char[]` arrays are not initializing properly, so I think the problem is that I am not passing the original `char[]` array "charr" to the `mergsort` function.

I am lost as to how to do this.  I borrowed the mergesort algorithm from the web, and it works on `int` arrays, but the simple change of changing `int[]` arrays to `char[]` arrays does not work.

How is it possible to get the `char[]` array that I want the sort done on to pass properly and initialize in the `mergesort` function?

The permutations look like this in the text file:

aaaab

aaaba

aabaa

abaaa

baaaa

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

int arr[243][6];

//This is the array that I want to store my strings
char *charr[243][6];

int c, i = 0 , j = 0;
FILE *file;
file = fopen("permutations.txt", "r");
if (file) {
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        // we are reading each char in the string
        //every time we hit a new line char (\n = 10)
        //advance the array one, otherwise add the
        // char
        if (c != 10) {
            arr[i][j] = c;
            j++;
        }
        else {
            arr[i][j] = c;
            sprintf(charr[i], "%d%d%d%d%d%d", arr[i][0], arr[i][1],
                arr[i][2], arr[i][3], arr[i][4]);
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}

if (strcmp(charr[0],charr[1]) < 0)
    printf("less\n");
else
   printf("other\n");

r_mergesort(charr,0,242);

for (int k = 0; k < 243; k++) {
    printf(charr[k]);
    for (int l = 0; l < 6; l++) {
        putchar(arr[k][l]);
    }
}
return 0;
}

/*l is for left index and r is right index of the sub-array*/
void r_mergesort (char arr[], int l, int r) {
    //base case
    if (l < r) {
        //divide
        int m = (l + r) /2;
        // recursively sort halves
        r_mergesort(arr, l, m);
        r_mergesort(arr, m + 1, r);
        // merge results
        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}

void merge (char arr[], int l, int m, int r) {
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;
    //  create temp arrays
    char left[n1], right[n2];
    // copy data to temp arrays
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        left[i] = arr[l + i];
    }
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        right[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];
    // merge the temp arrays back into arr[]
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (strcmp(left[i], right[j]) < 0) {
            arr[k] = left[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            arr[k] = right[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    //copy the remaining elements of left[]
    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k] = left[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    //copy the remaining elements of right[]
    while (i < n2) {
        arr[k] = right[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers, so pass the size of the array.

Comment: try `char *charr[243][6];` --> `char charr[243][7];`

Comment: That's the bigger issue. However, that would limit string length to 5 (all 243 of them...).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY when I do what you say, the strings do not print out, I get a lot of garbage.

Comment: `char arr[]` --> `char arr[][7]` The modified program you consider it

Comment: @lefunction What does your permutations.txt file look like? On possible permutation per-line or multiple possible permutations per-line. Post several lines. You may be able to make use of line-oriented input that would simplify the read quite a bit. Also, if you didn't pick up on this from the prior comment `char charr[243][6];` will need to be at minimum `char charr[243][7];`

Comment: @David C Rankin it is one permutation per line.

Comment: You can replace your entire read with `if (file) while (i < 243 && fgets (charr[i++], 7, file)) {}`. and for good measure, always initialize your character arrays. e.g. `char charr[243][7] = {{0}};`

Comment: `sprintf(charr[i], "%d%d%d%d%d%d"` --> `sprintf(charr[i], "%c%c%c%c%c%c"`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin something bizaar started happening when I tried your file read.  I had to double the number of iterations from 243 to 486 to get the whole file to pump into the array.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The three changes you suggested were the ones that got me on the right track.  I had to initialize then entire length of each string in the merge algorithm, it was not enough to say left[i] = arr[l + i].

Comment: @lefunction I explain in detail the issues involved in the example below. File I/O in C isn't difficult, but you have to pay the price to learn the subtleties or they will cause the exact problem you ran into. (i.e. the *line-oriented* input functions reading up to the `newline` (or character limit supplied). With a limit of `7` chars, the `newline` isn't read until the next read causing you to appear to have twice as many entries in your file (you don't, you are just reading blank lines that include the `newline` every other read). Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

While there is nothing wrong with *character-oriented* input (e.g. `getc`) if, as you describe, your `permutations.txt` contains one possible permutation per-line, then using *line-oriented* input will simplify your read (which I suspect is where a bulk of your problem lies). So let's get you reading your data file properly as a start to solving your issues.

Using *line-oriented* input, your primary functions are `fgets` and `getline`. Each has certain pluses and minuses. Since you are dealing exclusively with static declarations, we will use `fgets` below for the example.

One thing to be aware of with line-oriented input, is that `fgets` will read until a `newline` (`'\n'`) is encounter or the maximum number of characters specified (minus 1 leaving room for the nul-terminator). What this means in your case is, if you have declared `charr[243][7]` and have `6` chars per-line (plus the `'\n'` for a total of `7` chars) you will run into problems if you do not increase your string size by an additional character to allow the `'\n'` to be read as part of each line (and also providing space for the nul-terminator).

Basically what will happen is you will tell `fgets` to read a max of `7` chars which means it will read all `6` of your permutation characters, but leave the `'\n'` at the end of the line unread. Your next call to `fgets` will read only the `'\n'`. To solve the entire problem, simply declare `charr[243][8] = {{0}};` to allow a complete read of each line.

You may say, 'that doesn't sound much simpler' -- it is, I just wanted to make sure and give a thorough explanation so you don't end up caught in a subtle issue of reading 1-less that the whole line. Of course, since all line-oriented input functions, read and include the `'\n'` as part of their read, you will want to remove the newline from the stings stored in the array. After the explanation, hopefully the example will make the read much clearer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXR 243
#define MAXC 8

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char charr[MAXR][MAXC] = {{0}};
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    size_t i = 0;

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (i < MAXR && fgets (charr[i], MAXC, fp)) 
    {
        /* get length, strip trailing newline */
        size_t len = strlen (charr[i]);
        if (charr[i][len-1] == '\n') charr[i][len-1] = 0;

        printf (" charr[%zu] : %s\n", i, charr[i]);

        i++;
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}
```

The code above simply reads and prints (with the line index) each permutation read from the file given as the *first argument* to the program (or from `stdin` if no filename is given). It is just to confirm the read of your permutations.txt file to begin with.

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o bin/readperm readperm.c
```

**Test Input (permutations.txt)**

```
$ cat permutations.txt
123456
234561
345612
456123
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/readperm permutations.txt
 charr[0] : 123456
 charr[1] : 234561
 charr[2] : 345612
 charr[3] : 456123
```

While `fgets` and `getline` are the primary tools for *line-oriented* input, and I rarely recommend the `scanf` family of functions, if your permutations.txt file is exactly as you describe `fscanf` can be used very efficiently in this case. Generally, the choice of *format-string* and proper *format-specifiers* is what gives new C programmers fits. Since `fscanf` doesn't require that you read the newline, you can use the `char charr[243][7] = {{0}};` declaration and not have to worry about removing the included `newline`. Specifically, you can replace the read loop above with:

```
    while (i < MAXR && fscanf (fp, " %[^\n]%*c", charr[i]) == 1) 
    {
        printf (" charr[%zu] : %s\n", i, charr[i]);

        i++;
    }
```

Note the choice of format specifier `" %[^\n]%*c"`. The leading `space` between the opening `"` and `'%'` will skip any whitespace before the first character. The character *case* expression used as a *format-specifier* `%[^\n]` will read all characters up to, but not inlcuding, the `newline`. The *assignment-suppression* `%*c` will read and discard the `'\n'` without including it in your string (or in the match-count returned by `fscanf`).

**note** you could simply use a `" %s"` format specifier and accomplish the same read in your case, but that would have eliminated the explanation of the various parts of the *format-string* that is critical to understanding correct use of the `scanf` family of functions.

Lastly, **note** above the use of the return `== 1`. `fscanf` returns the number of successful conversions (according to the *format-specifiers*). Therefore you want to continue your read so long as `fscanf` makes a single conversion to string each time it is called. When it fails to make a proper conversion your read loop terminates (you can assign the return to a variable and check within the body of the loop to confirm `EOF` versus a read error)

Let me know when you get your read of permutations.txt sorted out and we will work on any lingering issues you have after confirming you have your read fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try `char *charr[243][6];` --> `char charr[243][7];`

`char arr[]` --> `char arr[][7]` The modified program you consider it

`sprintf(charr[i], "%d%d%d%d%d%d"` --> `sprintf(charr[i], "%c%c%c%c%c%c"`

– BLUEPIXY

The three changes you suggested were the ones that got me on the right track.  I had to initialize then entire length of each string in the merge algorithm, it was not enough to say left[i] = arr[l + i].

– lefunction